# monit mysql server blocked because of too many bad connections

Tags: mysql, debian, monit

Is there any tweak for monit or another way to monitor whether one server can access mysql on another server?

I tried it with monit but as you probably know, after 10 attempts, mysql blocks the server.

```
check host db1.server with address db1.server
   if failed port 3306 protocol mysql then alert
```

.

```
mysqli: host <host> is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

Comment: Do you mean that host `<host>` is the host that runs Monit, and that is is blocked by MySql because `<host>` failed to connect to `db1.server` too many times ?

Comment: <host> is the source server. and it doesnt fail to connect but it doesnt do what mysql considers a successful connection. it only happens with the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: I have also seen this issue with nagios, and would be interested in an elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** (total new answer)

I have Googled a bit about this issue and found some clue :

Seems that `MySql` does not really like when :

- a connection is made on port 3306 without authentication
- a socket is openened and then dropped without any SQL handshaking

So, a workaround could be to perform a real `MySql` connection and run a query.

Here is a way to do it. You will need to install `mysql-client` on the monitoring server and grant correct access on MySql server.

`Monit` check setup :

```
check program mysql with path "/root/mysql_check.sh"
  if status != 0 then alert
```

Script `mysql_check.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u<user> -p<password> --host=xx.xx.xx.xx <<END
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
END
```

Script `mysql_check.sh` should also be valid for a custom `Nagios` check.

---

I have tested this successfully (means can run the query remotely), but as far as i cannot reproduce the `blocked host` issue on my `MySql 5.5` server i cannot tell if this actually solves the issue.

Give it a try and tell me what the result is.

---

My references :

- http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.fr/2010/12/mysql-blocked-because-of-many.html
- http://www.openfusion.net/tags/nagios/

Comment: Nope. that doesnt work.

Comment: @Christian I've edited my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: Thats an interesting concept @user.. that should work but unfortunately its not a secure method cause the password would have to be stored in the sh file. of course, i could create a user with VERY basic privileges but still.. not my recommended way cause any access is a security flaw in my view.

Comment: @Christian Yes, i admit it is a security hole. You could also create a specific DB for monitoring purpose. By now i cannot see another way, sorry...

Comment: thanks for your time anyway. great concept you came up with but as our servers are PCI Compliant, I think that would cause us issues

Comment: thanks for this detail